# Gluing data for $\infty$-sheaves?

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, simplicial-presheaves

Let $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ be two $\infty$-sheaves on $X$ resp. $Y$. I want to understand exactly when we can "glue" $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ to give a $\infty$-sheaf on $X\cup_{U\sim V} Y$. Does anyone know a reference for this?

For ordinary sheaves the requirement is that you have some open cover of $X\cup Y$ and sheaves for each open of that cover that are suitable compatible as spelled out above Lemma 6.33.2 [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00AK). This amounts to $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ evaluating to equivalent objects in the target for the opens $U$ and $V$ that we glue $X$ and $Y$ together over. There should be an "obvious" higher analogue of this, just asking for a lot more coherence than a commuting diagram, but I don't know of a clever way to make this precise..

Comment: What are $X$, $Y$, $U$, and $V$? The answer would be very different if they are topological spaces, or in general objects in a site.

Comment: Oh, should have clarified that, thanks! 

So a priori I would want $X, Y, U$ and $V$ to all be (very nice) topological spaces. And by very nice I'd essentially only need topological manifolds, in case that is of any help.